# Run some code when the wordpress plugin exits

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

I am in a weird situation , working on a large wordpress environment with many plugins developed by different vendors. 
There is one plugin which is changing the default timezone for the entire website by running this line

```
$default_timezone = "Australia/Darwin";
date_default_timezone_set($default_timezone);
```

I know that this is wrong and the plugin should have used

```
get_option('timezone_string');
```

The plugin then uses at several places

```
$now = new Datetime()
```

to get the time. So For this particular plugin everything works but then its setting the default time as Darwin and for other plugins the current_time() function goes wrong.

And since this plugin is huge , Its becoming a problem to change it now. Is there a way that so that when this plugin's code is executed I can undo the default timezone set that it is doing ?

I hope I made myself clear !!

Comment: It'd be helpful if you can describe more on the situation. For example, is this a third party plugin or your own. If it's your own, you should probably modify your code and use the get_option(). And what exactly does this plugin do? Does it save any data to the db and put down the timestamp? I think the solution here wouldn't be something like you suggested which is to somehow undo the time setting change after script execution due to multiple reasons. So you should describe your situation with more context and other can then suggest possible solutions.

Comment: Its a website of a large corporate .  We do have access to the code. Different vendors have built different plugins from time to time. 

The plugin handles some back office functions which are pretty important for business.

Comment: I think you should change the code, especially if it's just in a few places where its setting the timezone.  If its simply changing loading order you can place the plugin in mu-plugins folder so that it loads first then add in a new plugin right after it and change back the timezone setting.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple options:

1. If the date code is within a class, you can extend it. Revert the timezone change in your custom destructor. Use your class instead of the one in the plugin.
2. Fix the plugin code yourself. Of course, this would increase future maintenance.
3. Report the problem to the plugin developer.
4. Explicitly specify the timezone in all other plugins instead of relying on the default.

Sorry there don't appear to be any good options.

Comment: Yes you are right .. These are probably the best options to move forward from here. I was just thinking if there is a possibility of a quick fix and then take more time to fix it properly.